# Why, in ie, is the absolute positioned logo to the right?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, firefox, css-position

This is my CSS code:

```
#header {
    width: 900px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
#logo {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
}
```

and the html...

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div id="logo"> <a href="http://projectstratos.com/" title="Home"><img src="logo-transparent.png" border="0"></a>
            </div>
            <!--End Logo-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The logo needs to stay absolute and under my content. In firefox it looks great but in ie the logo is to the right instead of the left. I am using the center div instead of the margin method of centering as in ie it doesn't work!

How can I move it to the left?

Comment: Which version of IE? Your code works for me in Chrome and IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/uhBMR/

Comment: Same under IE7, logo is top left.

Comment: I have just checked it under IE6, it is also positioned as expected, top left: http://jsfiddle.net/Q222c/. So, I guess something else (ie: something you haven't posted here) in your CSS/HTML/JS is affecting this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it needs to be offset from the centre and you know the width of the logo then you can set the width, set left to 50%, and use a negative margin to center it. Then once centered you can add to the margin to get the offset you want from the centre.

Example:

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;

    margin-left:-250px; /* This negative margin gets the logo in the centre */
    /* Adjust this value to get the offset you want. If you want to have it 100px to the left make it -350px, if you want it 50px to the right make it -200px */

    width:200px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try top and left?

```
#logo {
    top: 5px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: No because it needs to be offset from the center